# Client needs hands and figurines drawn in logo

Tags: logo, drawing

My client sent me a photo of a complex artwork of a figurine, in which she would like me to incorporate in her new logo. I am beyond stuck on what to do. I've tried a few things, but to be honest, drawing people is not my strong suit.

Are there any tricks or suggestions anyone can give me on how to give this look without copying the artwork? I've told her that a logo really should be simple so it's easy to remember and will work great on all platforms, but she really wants me to make it work. I've researched how to make a logo have energy and movement, but I'm not sure how to make this work because it's a stationary thing; the scribbles represent the energy in a person.

Her main idea is to have a figurine sitting in a hand (also not great at drawing lol)

Any suggestions would be great!

[image]

Comment: It might help if you were to show what you tried, and why that isn't working for you.  It might also be worthwhile pointing out to your client that logos with fine lines or intricate detail will not look so good at smaller sizes.

Comment: You either need to take control of the product and explain to her how logo design works and he business reasons for trusting you, the professional, to do what you do, or else it's maybe time to let this client go.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this situation, your solution needs to be as much about educating your client about logo design as it is about designing a logo.

As you have pointed out, the particular artwork she has provided is just about the worst possible thing you could use for a logo, as it will not scale at all.

Do some research on bad logo design, and gather examples where logos don't work for the exact reasons this image won't work. You will use these examples as part of the educational process.

You need to really understand what it is about this image that appeals to your client.  You hint at some of that in your question, but it is not clear if you are guessing, or if you have actually spoken to her about it. Is it the concept of contained energy?  Is it the idea of abstractions creating something more concrete? Or??

Then, I would present her with exactly what she wants--use the image she has given you and create the best design you possibly can with that image.  No matter how hard you try, it is probably going to be a failure, but give it your honest best.

Then provide at least two or three other options that illustrate the concepts that she wants, but do not use this image.

Do not present the different logo options side by side--make sure to present them in the context of mockups.  Show them on a business card mockup, on letterhead, etc.  Make sure you show examples where the logo based on the original sculpture doesn't work, but your other designs do.

This is a ton of work, I know, but in my experience, this process has garnered me the most success convincing a client that their idea simply isn't working.